# Programmatically set style for footnoteReference run

Tags: openxml, docx4j, footnotes

I have written a generator with docx4j that takes a proprietary data model as input and produces a docx file as output.

I try to add footnotes (and footnote-references), following the example here: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FootnoteAdd.java

However, I fail to see how I can add styling to the run that represents a footnoteReference. I create it exactly like in the example:

```
CTFtnEdnRef ftnednref = wmlObjectFactory.createCTFtnEdnRef(); 
JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.CTFtnEdnRef> ftnednrefWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRFootnoteReference(ftnednref); 
r.getContent().add( ftnednrefWrapped); 
ftnednref.setId( BigInteger.valueOf( i) );
```

How can I add styling information to `ftnednref`? Eventually, this "run" is a normal Run in my result, but it does not have the RStyle `FootnoteReference`, which means that it is not in superscript in my document. I figured this style should be applied automatically, but it isn't. My result looks like this:

```
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:highlight w:val="darkCyan"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:footnoteReference w:id="2"/>
</w:r>
```

It re-uses the `rPr` of the preceeding run. How can I make sure this footnoteReference-Run has the correct styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a sample document in Word, you can use the docx4j webapp or Helper Word AddIn, to generate corresponding Java code.

I this case, I got:

```
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="FootnoteReference"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-AU"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:footnoteReference w:id="1"/>
        </w:r>
```

and

```
        // Create object for r
        R r2 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r2); 
            // Create object for rPr
            RPr rpr2 = wmlObjectFactory.createRPr(); 
            r2.setRPr(rpr2); 
                // Create object for rStyle
                RStyle rstyle = wmlObjectFactory.createRStyle(); 
                rpr2.setRStyle(rstyle); 
                    rstyle.setVal( "FootnoteReference"); 
                // Create object for lang
                CTLanguage language2 = wmlObjectFactory.createCTLanguage(); 
                rpr2.setLang(language2); 
                    language2.setVal( "en-AU"); 
            // Create object for footnoteReference (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            CTFtnEdnRef ftnednref = wmlObjectFactory.createCTFtnEdnRef(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.CTFtnEdnRef> ftnednrefWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRFootnoteReference(ftnednref); 
            r2.getContent().add( ftnednrefWrapped); 
                ftnednref.setId( BigInteger.valueOf( 1) );
```

So the bit you need is:

```
            // Create object for rStyle
            RStyle rstyle = wmlObjectFactory.createRStyle(); 
            rpr.setRStyle(rstyle); 
                rstyle.setVal( "FootnoteReference");
```

You'll also want to define the FootnoteReference style in your styles part.

Comment: thanks, I don't have enough reputation yet to make my upvote visible. The solution is, basically, to add a "empty" run ("r2") with the desired styling and add the footnote reference to this new run instead of adding it to the run of the paragraph. Maybe the example I mention in my question should be adapted accordingly?